# Laravel datatable group data with same category

Tags: mysql, laravel, datatable, datatables

I have a table item. the values inserted in the table are

```
category item
-------- ----
Mobiles  Lava
Mobiles  Redmi
Vehicles Honda
Mobile   Oneplus
```

I want to show the above table as below in frontend using datatables. I have used `groupBy`, but it's not working.

```
Category      items
--------      -------------------
Mobiles       Lava, Oneplus, Redmi
Vehicles      Honda
```

Anyone can you please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT.

```
DB::table('items')
            ->select(DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(items) as `items`"))
            ->groupBy('Category')
            ->get();
```

If you want to use different SEPARATOR`(-)` instead of `(,)`

```
->select(DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(items SEPARATOR '-') as `items`"))
```